# Let $y=f(x)$ satisfy $y''' - ay''+a^2y'-a^3y = 0$ s.t $f(0)=1, f'(0)=0$ and $f''(0)=a^2$. How many positive roots does $f$ have?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Original question: if $a$ is a positive constant, let $y=f(x)$ be the solution of the equation $y''' - ay''+a^2y'-a^3y = 0$ such that $f(0)=1, f'(0)=0$ and $f''(0)=a^2$. How many positive values of x satisfy the equation $f(x)=0$?

What I did: I already found that $y = e^{ax} - \sin(ax)$. Now we want $e^{ax} - \sin(ax) = 0$. The textbook suggests to look at the graph and observe that two functions do not overlap for $x>0$. What I did:
$e^{ax} =   \sin(ax)$ =>  $ax =   \ln(\sin(ax))$. From here we know that $0 < \sin(ax) \leq 1$ => $\ln(\sin(ax)) \leq 0$, where $0<x \leq \frac{\pi}{2a}$. So if we want $f(x) = 0$, we would need $x = \frac{\pi}{2a}$ for RHS, but for LHS $x=0$, since $a>0$. Thus contradiction and there are not positive x that satisfy the equation $f(x)=0$. I was wondering if this is right way to think without looking at graphs?

Answer (score 1):

Remember $e^x>1+x$ and $\sin x<x$ for $x>0$.